# MVC different errors from required annotation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have a class named Address, like:

```
class Address
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "AD is required.")]
    public string AD{get; set;
}
```

In my model, I have two member of type `Address` (`HomeAddress` and `WorkAddress`) and in my view I render two partial views end each view contains an address. If my model it's not valid, I want to show two errors like: "`Home AD is required`" or "`Work AD is required`". Is it possible to achieve this using a single class and without creating custom validators?

Edit. I need to get the errors from the `ModelState`, so I can't use `@Html.ValidationMessageFor` because I need to show my errors in a special container

Comment: No, you can't unless you create a custom Required attribute, which doesn't make sense. Just create two different ViewModels.

Comment: By the way, I would be more concerned about using "AD" for Address. What's wrong with "Home Address" and "Word Address"?

Comment: You mean that I should create two classes?

Comment: Yes, What's wrong with that? It's better than writing a lot of code just to handle this, or doing some jquery hack.

Answer (score 0):

Possible here is what you are looking for:

```
public ActionResult HomeAction(Address model)
{
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.AD))
   {
      ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Home AD is required");
      return View(model);
   }
   // model.AD is valid here...
   return View();
}

public ActionResult WorkAction(Address model)
{
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.AD))
   {
      ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Work AD is required");
      return View(model);
   }
   // model.AD is valid here...
   return View();
}
```

Or using jQuery to check it before submitting:

In the View:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.AD, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

var ad = $.trim($('#AD').val());
if (ad.length == 0) {
   // _HomePartialView
   $('span[data-valmsg-for="AD"]').text('Home AD is invalid');
   // _WorkPartialView
   $('span[data-valmsg-for="AD"]').text('Work AD is invalid');
} else {
   // AD is valid here...
}
```

Comment: I have a single action: Edit... And can I use jQuery to edit the message from the required annotation?

Comment: @BudaGavril The first case: you can create another field/variable as a flag to classify `_HomePartial` and `_WorkPartial`. The second case: please check again for my updated answer.

Comment: All this just because you don't want to create two ViewModels?

Comment: @ataravati ya. No need to create 2 classes with a same mission/same property.

Comment: @HappyCoding, what in your solution justifies not creating two ViewModels?